# How to print exact sql query before execute in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am working on an application using Zend framework 2. I'm using TableGateway to select, insert, update and delete query.

**1. My question is how to print exact sql query before executing INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statement?** For *SELECT* statement here is my code which is working for me.

```
$selectedTable = new TableGateway($this->tblName, $this->dbAdapter);
$sql = $selectedTable->getSql();
$select = $sql->select();

if ($trace) {
    echo "<br>" . $sql->getSqlstringForSqlObject($select) . "<br>";
    exit;
} 
else {
    $resultSet = $selectedTable->selectWith($select);
    unset($selectedTable);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

**2.** For last inserted id I'm using this code and working fine.

```
$selectedTable = new TableGateway($this->tblName, $this->dbAdapter);
$selectedTable->insert($dataArray); 
$insertId = $selectedTable->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue();
unset($selectedTable);
return $insertId;
```

But for **UPDATE** how to get last updated id? and for **DELETE** how to get affected row? Because for *UPDATE* and *DELETE* this code is not working.

Can anyone suggest how to do these job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** There should be no difference nor difficulties, do it exaclty the same way on your `$insert` object. Here how I perform Sql insert and get the SQL string:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
$insert = $sql->insert('table');
[...]
$sqlString = $insert->getSqlString($this->dbAdapter->getPlatform());
```

**2.** When you insert a value, you do not know what will be the generated value `id` before insertion, but you will only know it ater insertion. That's why there is the `getLastGeneratedValue-)` method for inserted values.

But when you update or delete a value, its `id` is already defined and you can read it. So all you have to do is to read it from your database. Perform a select before updating or deleting your(s) objetct(s) and you will know all the ids you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me how to use getaffectedrows() with update and delete using TableGateway?